# Random pc's in domain lose connection with network drives

Tags: windows, windows-domain, dfs

I encounter problem in my network where network drives deployed by GPO temporarily cease to work on singular computers (one-two percent at a time).

While problem is present there is normal connection to all other services and also normal pings to DC and drives hosts.
All other computers in domain work, problem is usually present in singular percent of machines. I didn't noticed correlation between problematic machines (VLAN's, domain groups).

I'm looking for a checklist where to look in order to either remove problem member-side or locate precise locations to check for domain admin.

**Problematic state:**

- Network drives won't open. Explorer hangs out for a while and finally throws connection error.
- "net use" either hangs for long period of time or shows "Disconnected" and "Reconnecting" statuses for every drive.
- Sometimes drives even show free space, sometimes they indicate disconnection
- "gpupdate" usually ends with "Processing of Group Policy failed (...) attempt to read gpt.ini was not successful" (sometimes it works normally though)
- In last case, I've just noticed inability to connect with RPC server via MMC. I don't know yet if it's correlated.

**Problem ceases after:**

- CoA termination with port bounce
- It does not cease after simple connection or PC restart (even when resetting whole TCP/IP stack)
- usually next day

**Topology:**

- Domain branch with dual DC
- Two separate DFS servers, few folders from each are mounted as network drives
- This part of network is wholly equipped with Cisco, members are connected via desk phones (but AFAIK there are just simple switches inside?)

Comment: What third-party security tools are in-use (eg, anti-virus, firewall, etc)?  I would suggest monitoring how your group policies are enforced (eg, with ProcMon).  I often see policies removed (cleared from the registry), then re-applied during GP update cycles.  When this occurs, there can be a brief interruption to users.  Third-party security software can also interfere with file and network access, unless properly excluded or white-listed.  Perhaps consider moving your network drive mappings to your netlogon script to see if the problem goes away.